# complex query in PyTables using table.where

Tags: python, where-clause, pytables

How can I do sokmething like that: (if possible)

```
options = {'topLimit': 22.3, 'downLimit': 9}

for row in tab.where('value < options['topLimit']'):
    #whatever
    ...
    ...
```

Can we put something like `options['topLimit']` or something similar inside the `where` condition??

If not, how can it be done?

P.D: Note that this is a very simple example....I know the solution for this case is:

```
for row in tab.where('value < 22.3'):
```

I am thinking about much more complex situations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass options in as the condvars argument to where:

```
options = {'topLimit': 22.3, 'downLimit': 9}

for row in tab.where('value < topLimit', options):
    #whatever
```

See the documentation for more details [1].

1. http://pytables.github.io/usersguide/libref/structured_storage.html?highlight=where#tables.Table.where